# How to fix "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: TLS Server certificate issued after 2019-04-16 and anchored by a distrusted legacy Symantec root CA"

Tags: java, ssl, mqtt, paho, sslhandshakeexception

I got the exception below while connecting to a MQTT Server with Java and self signed certificates. I used VeriSign-Class 3-Public-Primary-Certification-Authority-G5.pem as cacert.pem.

The code is for an Linux server but currently I'm programming it on IntelliJ IDEA.

```
public class TestMQTT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String serverUrl = "ssl://A35IXNRWYOLJWQ.iot.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:8883";
        String caFilePath = "H:/Users/Joschua/IdeaProjects/ServerMain/src/de/AirConnect/SSL/cacert.pem";
        String clientCrtFilePath = "H:/Users/Joschua/IdeaProjects/ServerMain/src/de/AirConnect/SSL/Certificate.cer";
        String clientKeyFilePath = "H:/Users/Joschua/IdeaProjects/ServerMain/src/de/AirConnect/SSL/client.key"; //privat key


        MqttClient client;
        try {
            client = new MqttClient(serverUrl, "anyID");
            MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();

            options.setConnectionTimeout(60);
            options.setKeepAliveInterval(60);
            options.setMqttVersion(MqttConnectOptions.MQTT_VERSION_3_1);


            SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = getSocketFactory(caFilePath,
                    clientCrtFilePath, clientKeyFilePath, "");
            options.setSocketFactory(socketFactory);

            System.out.println("starting connect the server...");
            client.connect(options);
            System.out.println("connected!");
    .......

    private static SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory(final String caCrtFile,
                                                     final String crtFile, final String keyFile, final String password)
            throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        // load CA certificate
        X509Certificate caCert = null;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(caCrtFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            caCert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
            // System.out.println(caCert.toString());
        }

        // load client certificate
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(crtFile));
        X509Certificate cert = null;
        while (bis.available() > 0) {
            cert = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(bis);
            // System.out.println(caCert.toString());
        }

        // load client private key
        PEMParser pemParser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(keyFile));
        Object object = pemParser.readObject();
        PEMDecryptorProvider decProv = new JcePEMDecryptorProviderBuilder()
                .build(password.toCharArray());
        JcaPEMKeyConverter converter = new JcaPEMKeyConverter()
                .setProvider("BC");
        KeyPair key;
        if (object instanceof PEMEncryptedKeyPair) {
            System.out.println("Encrypted key - we will use provided password");
            key = converter.getKeyPair(((PEMEncryptedKeyPair) object)
                    .decryptKeyPair(decProv));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unencrypted key - no password needed");
            key = converter.getKeyPair((PEMKeyPair) object);
        }
        pemParser.close();

        // CA certificate is used to authenticate server
        KeyStore caKs = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        caKs.load(null, null);
        caKs.setCertificateEntry("ca-certificate", caCert);
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        tmf.init(caKs);

        // client key and certificates are sent to server so it can authenticate
        // us
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(null, null);
        ks.setCertificateEntry("certificate", cert);
        ks.setKeyEntry("private-key", key.getPrivate(), password.toCharArray(),
                new java.security.cert.Certificate[] { cert });
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory
                .getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(ks, password.toCharArray());

        // finally, create SSL socket factory
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        context.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        return context.getSocketFactory();
    }

}
```

The output is:

```
MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: TLS Server certificate issued after 2019-04-16 and anchored by a distrusted legacy Symantec root CA: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:736)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: TLS Server certificate issued after 2019-04-16 and anchored by a distrusted legacy Symantec root CA: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:320)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:263)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:258)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:641)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:460)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:360)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:392)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:441)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:419)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1180)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1091)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.SSLNetworkModule.start(SSLNetworkModule.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:722)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: TLS Server certificate issued after 2019-04-16 and anchored by a distrusted legacy Symantec root CA: CN=VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5, OU="(c) 2006 VeriSign, Inc. - For authorized use only", OU=VeriSign Trust Network, O="VeriSign, Inc.", C=US
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.SymantecTLSPolicy.checkNotBefore(SymantecTLSPolicy.java:189)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.SymantecTLSPolicy.checkDistrust(SymantecTLSPolicy.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.CADistrustPolicy$1.checkDistrust(CADistrustPolicy.java:54)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.EndEntityChecker.check(EndEntityChecker.java:167)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:277)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:221)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:625)
    ... 13 more
```

I tried to connect to the server with MQTT.fx (Windows program) and it worked.

Hope you can help me.
Greetings Joschua

Comment: The error message suggests that you are not dealing with a self-signed certificate as you claim but with a certificate issued by Symantec.

Comment: @SteffeUllrich But in the instructions of the provider was specified to use this certificate unconditionally. Do you know how I can use the certificate from Symantec in the code?

Comment: See https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/jdk-distrusting-symantec-tls-certificates where Oracle describes why they made the verification fail and how to work around in order  to make it succeed again.

Comment: They need a new certificate.  As @SteffenUllrich indicates everyone has stopped trusting Symantec certs issued before December 1, 2017.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have now edited the Java.security file and it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For Linux**

I am able to resolve this issue by comment out the line `jdk.security.caDistrustPolicies=SYMANTEC_TLS` in `java.security` file.
In my case, this file is located in `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.232.b09-0.el7_7.x86_64/jre/lib/security/java.security`

You should be able to find it in your environment by using the following command `alternatives --config java`

**Note 1 :** The Symantec cert was distrusted for a reason and trust it at your own risk.

**Note 2 :** If you are using Gradle to build, you need to kill the gradle daemon first, otherwise gradle still use old jvm security configuration.

Comment: In windows for java 8 it is similar: The `java.security` file is located in `\..your-jdk-installation-path..\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-3\jre\lib\security\java.security`

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows (OpenJDK)**

I could find java.security file under [C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-11-openjdk-11.0.7-1\lib\security](http://C:%5CProgram%20Files%5CRedHat%5Cjava-11-openjdk-11.0.7-1%5Clib%5Csecurity) but i couldn't find **caDistrustPolicies** in that file.

After searching for a long long time finally i found the solution which worked.

```
C:\Program Files\RedHat\java-11-openjdk-11.0.7-1\conf\security\java.security
```

This is the file i commented below line and restarted VS Code and it worked like charm

```
#jdk.security.caDistrustPolicies=SYMANTEC_TLS
```

---